# Minimal permissions for login: admin on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, permissions, app.yaml

In App Engine Python2.7 there's an option to configure a handler to check for auth from Google by using the `login: admin` mechanism in `app.yaml` (as described here [app.yaml docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element))

So usually I'd be giving user the role of Project > Viewer in order to give them access to these admin protected handlers, but that seems like an overkill.

What's the minimal permission needed in order to access those handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles) you can find the Predefined App Engine roles and their description.

Regarding the `login:admin` element please keep in mind that

> If the user is not an administrator for the application, they are given an error message regardless of the auth_fail_action setting. If the user is an administrator, the handler proceeds.

as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_login).

More information about handlers can be found in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers).

Please let me know if these tips were helpful.